# Prove ${a_n} = \lim_{n \to \infty } \sum\nolimits_{k \ge 1} {{1 \over {{k^2}}}} $ Converges by using Cauchy's criteria

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, cauchy-sequences

> Prove ${a_n} = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty } \sum\nolimits_{k \ge 1} {{1 \over {{k^2}}}} $ Converges by using Cauchy's criteria.

What I did:
Let $n, m=n+k \in \mathbb{N}$.

$$\left| {{a_m} - {a_n}} \right| = \left| {{a_{n + k}} - {a_n}} \right| = \left| {\sum\limits_{l = n + 1}^{n + k} {{1 \over {{l^2}}}} } \right| \le k \cdot {1 \over {{{(n + 1)}^2}}} \le {k \over n}$$

At this phase I need to choose $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall m,n>N: \left| {{a_m} - {a_n}} \right| < \varepsilon$

The problem is that $k\over n$ depends on $k$. How to "correct" this?

Comment: The bound you obtain is too big. A typical idea is to gather the terms in the sum by groups of size a geometric progression ( e.g. powers of $2$), then bound each group by their first term repeated many times.

Comment: Let me say it better. Write $1+\left(\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}\right)+ \left(\frac{1}{4^2}+\frac{1}{5^2}+\frac{1}{6^2}+\frac{1}{7^2}\right)+ ...<1+\left(\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^2}\right)+ \left(\frac{1}{4^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}\right)+ ...=1+\frac{2}{2^2}+\frac{4}{4^2}+...$. You get a geometric series. The same can be done with the chunk of the series you have in Cauchy's criterion.

Comment: Is it just me or do the big absolute value symbols look green and red even though I don't see any coloring in the source code?

Comment: I'll give it a shot. thanks!

Comment: @user2345215, You should get some sleep ;)

Comment: @user2345215 remember that monitors only project Red, Blue and Green and combine them to get the other colors. It might be a defect of the screen.

Comment: @ABC Mystery solved. My screen is innocent. I thought there was something wrong with MathJax, but that was also not it. It's Microsoft with his "ClearType" text. But still thanks for your suggestion :) You learn something new every day. Here's how it looks http://i.stack.imgur.com/Xm87e.png

Comment: I suppose you wanted to write $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{k^2}$ instead of $\sum_{k\ge1} \frac1{k^2$. Otherwise you are taking limit $n\to\infty$ of something, which does not depend on $n$. (So it would be a limit of a constant sequence.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak I would go even further and add that the index $n$ for $a_{n}$ is irrelevant, since $n$ is a dummy variable which disappears when taking the limit $\lim\limits_{n \to + \infty}$...

Comment: Sorry for the typo in my previous comment. Of course, I wanted to write $\sum_{k\ge1} \frac1{k^2}$ (as opposed to $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k^2}$.

Comment: @jibe You are right. The OP probably means $a_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{k^2}$, i.e., $a_n$ is the $n$-th partial sum; and they ask about $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=m+1}^n\frac1{k^2}
&\le\sum_{k=m+1}^n\frac1{k(k-1)}\\
&=\sum_{k=m+1}^n\left(\frac1{k-1}-\frac1k\right)\\
&=\frac1m-\frac1n
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Oh snap. How could I forget this identity...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more general approach suppose $\sum a_n$ is a divergent series of positive terms and denote $s_n$ its partial sum.

We shall prove using Cauchy's criterion that $\sum a_n/s_n^2 $ converges. Given $\varepsilon>0$. There is some $n_0$ such that $s_{n_0}> 1/ \varepsilon$. Then for $q> p\ge n_0\,$ we have

\begin{align}\sum_{k=p+1}^q\frac{a_n}{s_n^2}<\sum_{k=p+1}^q\frac{a_n}{s_n(s_{n-1})}
=\sum_{k=p+1}^q\frac{s_n-s_{n-1}}{s_n(s_{n-1})}\\=\sum_{k=p+1}^q\frac{1}{s_{n-1}}-\frac{1}{s_{n}}=\frac{1}{s_p}-\frac{1}{s_q}\\<\frac{1}{s_p}\le\frac{1}{s_{n_0}}<\varepsilon\end{align}

Note that if $a_n=1$, the above proposition give us that $\sum1/n^2$ convergence using Cauchy's criterion.